# Layout managers visibility problem

Tags: java, awt

I have problem with panels. I have one main panel main_panel, at top I have ComboBox, 
based on selected item in combobox I need to show one of two panels under  (bith have lot  of buttons on positions x,y. if selected_item_1 then panel_1 visible,if selected_item_2 thenpanel two visible). How to add button to child_panel on exact position locX,locY?

Answer (score 1):

[CardLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) is ideal for this type of behaviour.

> A CardLayout object is a layout
>   manager for a container. It treats
>   each component in the container as a
>   card. Only one card is visible at a
>   time, and the container acts as a
>   stack of cards. The first component
>   added to a CardLayout object is the
>   visible component when the container
>   is first displayed.

Answer (score 1):

It's a job for [CardLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html). besides, if content must change according to a selection, maybe you should go the [JTabbedPane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html) way ...